# Name or service not known exception on starting Neo4j

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I remove completely and install Neo4j graph database again.After that I get Exception when I tried to start Neo4j service on debian server in the following segment:

```
Failed to get local hostname java.net.UnknownHostException: brain.kaankilic: brain.kaankilic: Name or service not known
    at java.net.UnknownHostException: brain.kaankilic: brain.kaankilic: Name or service not known
    at  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.getLocalHostName(ContextUtil.java:32)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.addHostNameAsProperty(ContextUtil.java:41)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction.begin(ConfigurationAction.java:56)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:276)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:148)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:130)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:157)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:143)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:106)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:56)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at  at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:121)
    at  at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:154)
    at  at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:132)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:67)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfigurator(Bootstrapper.java:215)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:93)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:57)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: brain.kaankilic: Name or service not known
    at  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at  at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at  at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
```

How can I fix that problem?

Thanks for interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `localhost` in your `neo4j.properties` and `neo4j-server.properties` with `127.0.0.1`.

Alternatively you might change your settings in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I think the wrong hostname is that: brain.kaankilic ? So when I turned it to localhost the problem will be fixed.Oh nice.Thank you for your answer.